# .HTACCESS redirect with if statement

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I use **.HTACCESS** to redirect only at certain times of the day? 
For instance if `getHours()` is **even**, redirect.
If `getHours()` is **not even** do nothing.

How can I incorporate below in the `.htaccess`?

```
var abcde = new Date();
if (abcde.getHours()%2==0){redirect here}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, have you looked at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: there is a `TIME_HOUR` property that you can use `RewriteCond` on. It would be cumbersome, but something like this would work:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  >=2
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  <=8
```

would mean that the Rewrite statements would only be executed if the hour of day is between 2am and 8am. For your example, you could try:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =0 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =6 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =8 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =10 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =12 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =14 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =16 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =18 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =20 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}  =22
```

Cumbersome, but would not require Javascript or anything else of that sort.

Comment: Thanks... that's just what I needed and not that cumbersome.

Comment: p.s. do you know how to add the actual redirect in there? It will be a certain url like     http://www.sample.com/sample

Comment: You can do something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` at the end (this redirects all requests to `index.php`: I use this with the CodeIgniter PHP framework).

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess`'s syntax is very limited. I'm not aware of a way to compare dates or times using pure Apache/.htaccess syntax. Stuff like that is not what it was designed for.

You *could* do something with a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) that calls an external script, which returns rewrite rules according to the time of day, but that would be silly.

Do the check in a server-side language like PHP, do the check there, and do a header redirect (or include the desired content using `include()`) when you're done.

Comment: @gravity good point. Basically yes, but it might be better to do an include() in that case. I updated the paragraph.

Comment: because I am actually doing a redirect but I used javascript. And that is bad for google, correct? The page you end up on might be different then the one from the initial search, that's bad, correct?

Comment: @gravityboy a Javascript redirect is indeed bad. A `include()` should be the safest way.